# Where should store auth token: Apollo Cache or Local Storage?

Tags: local-storage, apollo-client, apollo-cache-inmemory

Since Apollo has Apollo Cache for storing local data. I want to store `auth token` inside the Apollo cache instead of local storage. By store to Apollo Cache, help me clear `auth token` and other caching data when user logout without caring about local storage data.

My question is: Is it OK if I store `auth token` in Apollo Cache? Because example of Authentication from Apollo website is using local storage for storing `auth token`, this make me confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to store `auth token` in `Local Storage` instead of `Apollo Cache` because I made benchmark to measure speed of retrieving `token` from `Local Storage` and `Apollo Cache`,result is: retrieve from `Local Storage` faster than `Apollo Cache` around 3 ~ 4 times

Comment: Local Storage is against [OWASP security guidelines for JWT storage](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/JSON_Web_Token_for_Java_Cheat_Sheet.md#symptom-4)